# How do I select all disabled decendants using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to select all disabled decandants of a given element, in my particular instance a table cell and then enable them.

NOTE that there may be elements that are not "inputs"

I have tired the following with no success

```
$("#myCell [disabled='disabled']").removeAttr('disabled')
```

and

```
$("#myCell [disabled='disabled']").attr('disabled','')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#myCell :input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
```

The [`:input`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/input) selector is going to select all input elements, and the [`:disabled`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/disabled) selector is going to select elements that are disabled. You could probably just have the `:disabled` selector but it doesn't hurt to have both and is probably marginally faster to do so.

Comment: This one won't work for me as I have other elements that are not input elements, selects for one, labels and thanks to the wonders of ASP.net tables and spans too

Comment: ...? I'm not sure how that is a problem knowing what the two selectors do?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$("#myCell *[disabled='disabled']").removeAttr("disabled");
```

This * selector means 'all elements'